# AWS Personalize: "in User Class: com.amazonaws.concierge.exceptions.InvalidFormatException : Dataset has fewer than 1000 interactions"

Tags: amazon-web-services, machine-learning, recommendation-engine, amazon-personalize

I'm uploading data to AWS Personalize. It has millions of interactions. I am including multiple metadata fields, marking them all as categorical. I am getting this error. Thinking maybe once Personalize groups by all the categorical fields, there are some partitions that have below 1000 interactions. But not sure. Any ideas?

Comment: The minimum requirements are 1000 interactions where those interactions must be across a minimum of 25 different users with at least 2 interactions each. Does your interactions dataset meet that criteria? Also, are you specifying an eventType when creating your solution? If so, that will filter out interactions that do not match the evenType. If creating a domain recommender, you must have interactions with event types required by the recommender being created.

Comment: ok thanks. where did you find that qualification? Anyways, you're right. I had a bug in my code that was making every product unique so the users didn't have 2+ interactions each

Comment: Not super easy to find but it's documented in a couple places: on the [quotas](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/limits.html) page and [recording events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/personalize/latest/dg/recording-events.html#recording-events-requirements) page.

Comment: Check whether all the records are filled properly with out any blans